# Different answer interrogate elasticsearch with java or cmd

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've got a problem when I interrogate `elasticsearch` with `java`.

So when I execute this command in cmd, I retrieve the exact desired answer :

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/movies2/movie/_search?pretty=1" -d @queryMovies
```

And here is queryMovies:

```
{
"query":{
    "bool": {
      "must"   : { "match": { "fields.title": "Star Wars" }},
      "should" : { "match": { "fields.directors": "George Lucas" }}
    }
  }
}
```

But with this java code where the query is actually the same :

```
public class Connection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY);
        client.addTransportAddress(
                        new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                                InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.append("{\n" +
                        "\"query\":{\n" +
                        "    \"bool\": {\n" +
                        "      \"must\"   : { \"match\": { \"fields.title\": \"Star Wars\" }},\n" +
                        "      \"should\" : { \"match\": { \"fields.directors\": \"George Lucas\" }}\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "  }\n" +
                        "}\n");

        String indexToSearch    = "movies2";
        String docType          = "movie";

        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(query.toString());
        searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
        try {
            searchResponse = client.prepareSearch(indexToSearch)
                    .setTypes(docType)
                    .setSource(searchSourceBuilder)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error performing search on index[" + indexToSearch + "] and docType[" + docType + "] using query[" + query.toString() + "]. Error is: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        //write the retrieved json in a file.json
        CrunchJSONFileWrite crunchJSONFileWrite = new CrunchJSONFileWrite("test");
        crunchJSONFileWrite.fillFile(searchResponse);

        client.close();
    }
}
```

I retrieve the answer I want but there are some extra unwanted part in the answer  like this one where the director isn't George Lucas or, Star Wars isn't in the title:

```
{
        "_index": "movies2",
        "_type": "movie",
        "_id": "4484",
        "_score": 11.219259,
        "_source": {
          "fields": {
            "directors": [
              "Barry Skolnick"
            ],
            "release_date": "2001-12-26T00:00:00Z",
            "rating": 6.3,
            "genres": [
              "Comedy",
              "Drama",
              "Sport"
            ],
            "image_url": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2ODk0OTMyNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTcyMTMyMQ@@._V1_SX400_.jpg",
            "plot": "A soccer star jailed for assault leads a group of inmates in a match against prison guards.",
            "title": "Mean Machine",
            "rank": 4484,
            "running_time_secs": 5940,
            "actors": [
              "Vinnie Jones",
              "David Kelly",
              "David Hemmings"
            ],
            "year": 2001
          },
          "id": "tt0291341",
          "type": "add"
        }
      }
```

I checked for topics like this one [query elasticsearch with java with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041792/query-elasticsearch-with-java-with-json) but none helped

Thank you for your reading and help

Comment: `simpleQueryStringQuery` is not a method that takes a JSON DSL query in argument. In Java, you need to build your JSON query using `QueryBuilders.boolQuery()` and `QueryBuilders.matchQuery()`.

Comment: @Val Thank you very much for your help, that solves my problem ! :)